# In mrskew, can I calculate human readable timestamps from tim?

Tags: oracle, perl, instrumentation

I'm using [mrskew](https://method-r.com/man/mrskew) by [Method-R](https://method-r.com) to analyze Oracle SQL Trace files.

I want to list all database calls similar to the output of *calls.rc*
But instead of the value of *$tim*, I'd print a human readable date format.

Raw data (minimal obfuscated):

```
*** 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** SESSION ID:(1391.49878) 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** CLIENT ID:() 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** MODULE NAME:(JDBC Thin Client) 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** CLIENT DRIVER:(jdbcthin : 12.2.0.1.0) 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
*** ACTION NAME:() 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
...
WAIT #0: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= 491 driver id=1413697536 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=12568091328841
=====================
PARSING IN CURSOR #18446744071522016088 len=71 dep=0 uid=88 oct=7 lid=88 tim=12568091329190 hv=2304270232 ad='61e4d11e0' sqlid='5kpbj024phrws'
/*Begin.Work*/
SELECT ...
END OF STMT
PARSE #18446744071522016088:c=147,e=148,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=957996380,tim=12568091329190
...
EXEC #18446744071522016088:c=683,e=11406,p=0,cr=2,cu=11,mis=0,r=1,dep=0,og=1,plh=957996380,tim=12568091341788
CLOSE #18446744071522016088:c=27,e=27,dep=0,type=1,tim=12568091343665
XCTEND rlbk=0, rd_only=0, tim=12568091343769
```

Current output (compacted for readability):

```
          END-TIM       LINE       SQL_ID CALL-NAME STATEMENT-TEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  12568091.341788         36 5kpbj024phrws EXEC     /*Begin.Work*/ SELECT ...
  12568091.343769         42               XCTEND
```

Expected output (please don't cricicise my not correct subsecond calculation):

```
                  END-TIME LINE        SQL_ID CALL-NAME STATEMENT-TEXT  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-11-26 10:06:01.341788   36 5kpbj024phrws EXEC     /*Begin.Work*/ SELECT ...
2020-11-26 10:06:01.343769   42               XCTEND
```

I assume I can use [POSIX:strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX#strftime) to format the timestamp properly, but I need a way to generate an epoch timestamp from the timestamp at the begin of the tracefile

```
*** 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
```

and then an offset for each *$tim* relative to this begin of tracefile.
I hope methodr toolset can provide this. It should be easier for me to explain, when (in human readable form) which activity started.

Comment: What is the format of that timestamp? It looks like it might be something related to Julian day, but I can't work out how it's calculated.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle is not very helpful here. 
It can be epoch, but more often it's second since a given beginning - mostly the start of the instance. 
You can see a good summary here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:40474454846835

Comment: Ah, right, it seems I was confused. Yes, `tim=xxxx` is clearly an epoch second number. I was looking at the numbers like `12568091.341788` in your second example. Converting epoch seconds into nicely-formatted dates is simple enough. I'll write an answer now.

Comment: @DaveCross Oracle tim values are “microseconds-since” values, but as Martin noted, the tim values in modern Oracle trace files are _not_ generally Unix epoch-based values. The “trick” to converting an Oracle tim into a human-readable time is to establish the correspondence between a line beginning with "***" and the its corresponding tim value, and then using that offset to calculate what time a tim implies.

Comment: @MartinBerger, are you aware of our [mrwhen](https://method-r.com/man/mrwhen) Workbench utility? It will get you part-way to the finish line, at least. Jeff and I are already considering changing the mrskew spec so that it will process mrwhen output, and store the human-readable time value in a named variable that you can group, or filter, or select by.

Answer (score 2):

Generating an epoch seconds number from a string date is simple enough. [Time::Local](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local) has functions to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Local 'timelocal_posix';

my $date = '2020-11-26 10:06:01.867';

# Split the date apart
my ($yr, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec, $micro) = split /[- :.]/, $date;

# Note necessary adjustments to month and year
say timelocal_posix($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon - 1, $yr - 1900);
```

Comment: This is a great solution in pure perl! 
I'm sorry to say I'm searching for a solution in the specific tool [mrskew](https://method-r.com/man/mrskew). 
It is written in perl but compiled into a binary, so I can't extend it easily - it provides interesting methods to extend it's native functionality, but I struggle doing exactly what you show here in this specific tool.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of comments by @DaveCross and @CaryMillsap my processing is now:

1. from the tracefile create an intermediate file similar to

   ```
   *** 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867

         END-TIM       LINE       SQL_ID CALL-NAME STATEMENT-TEXT
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   XCTEND tim=12568091341788 e=2 dep=0          36 5kpbj024phrws EXEC     /*Begin.Work*/ SELECT ..
   XCTEND tim=12568091343769 e=1 dep=0          42               XCTEND
   ```

   using in calls.rc

   ```
   sprintf("XCTEND tim=%-20d e=%-5d dep=0 %10d %10d %10d  %13s %-40.40s %-.46s",  $tim*1000000, $line,($e+$ela)*1000000, $parse_id, $exec_id, $sqlid, "· "x$dep.$name.(scalar(@bind)?"(".join(",",@bind).")":""), "· "x$dep.$sql)
   ```
2. modify the result to have somewhere on top

   ```
   *** 2020-11-26 10:06:01.867
   ```
3. process this file with [mrwhen](https://method-r.com/man/mrwhen)
4. get rid of unwantent parts by

   ```
    sed -E 's/XCTEND t.{37}//'
   ```

In more detail it's documented [here](https://berxblog.blogspot.com/2021/01/convert-sql-trace-to-list-of-database.html).